# Try and getOrElse scala

Tags: scala

```
val label = Try("here_a").getOrElse("here_b")
```

In the case where `here_a` is not found, this is not falling back to `here_b`. Why is the `.getOrElse` not functioning?

Thanks @jwvh. These values are sting files paths and thus the exception is the following `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:`

As per Andrew James Ramirez's comment I tried this but issue persists.

`Try(throw new Exception("FAIL here_a")).getOrElse("here_b")`

I have also tried

`Try(throw new Exception("FileNotFoundException here_a")).getOrElse("here_b")`

*Edit*

It seems I may have oversimplified this question for SO. Some more context. The string is actually a file path. Perhaps this is making a difference?

Effectively, a `json` file may be found in one of two possible locations. I thus wish to try the first location and if a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is returned, fall back on the second location. This is what I presently have:

`val input_file = Try(throw new Exception("FAIL location_a/file_a.json")).getOrElse("location_b/file_a.json")`

*Edit* V2

I am embarrassed to say that I found the simple error. I am running this scala code on `spark` and I forgot to repackage in between testing. `sbt package` was all that was required. :-/

Comment: Both of your new examples return the "here_b" string. If you're getting a different result then it's unrelated to the code you've presented here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you misunderstood Try. and .getOrElse

Definition of Try :

> The Try type represents a computation that may either result in an exception, or return a successfully computed value. It's similar to, but semantically different from the scala.util.Either type.

```
scala> Try("here_a")
res1: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(here_a)

scala> Try("here_a").get
res2: String = here_a

scala> Try(throw new Exception("FAIL here_a")).getOrElse("here_b")
res3: String = here_b

scala>
```

It only fails if you throw Exception. null is still a value.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. How general can the exception be? My exception is `FileNotFoundException` and I have tried `FAIL` and it with no luck

Comment: thanks. It helped me to understand Try, and getOrElse

Answer (score 3):

`Try()` returns either a `Success(x)` or a `Failure(e)`, where `x` is the successful value returned and `e` is the exception that was thrown. `getOrElse()` unwraps the `Success` or supplies a default value.

If you're not getting the "OrElse" then your code isn't throwing a catchable exception.

Answer (score 1):

It works as you expect it should.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_40).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val label = Try(throw new RuntimeException("here_a")).getOrElse("here_b")
label: String = here_b
```

Please provide more context in your question if you feel this answer is insufficient.

Comment: Thanks Synesso. I embarassingly forgot to run `sbt package` in-between changes